# How can I export a .jar file with maven Java project in Apache NetBeans IDE 12.4

Tags: java, build

I've made a project in Apache NetBeans IDE 12.4 and can't find a way to export the project.
There aren't any helpful tutorial in YouTube either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in terminal write : mvn build ,then you can find your project jarfile in Target directory of project

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't walk

Comment: make sure in terminal you are exactly in the project folder/directory,then install maven using link : https://www.baeldung.com/install-maven-on-windows-linux-mac

Comment: you can vote this conversation to other see and use it

Comment: I can't, I don't have any reputation